# Рандомный выбор между словами

Tags: php

Допустим у меня есть две переменные

```
$a = 'odin';
$b = 'dva';
```

Как мне сделать рандомный выбор между ними? Т.е чтобы выводило рандомно или $a или $b

Answer (score 2):

> *чтобы выводило рандомно или $a или $b*

Сохранить переменные в массив, и с помощью [array_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php) получать случайный его элемент:

```
$a = 'odin';
$b = 'dva';
$words = [$a, $b];

echo $words[ array_rand($words) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаём массив и кладём туда ваши переменные. Затем для функции `rand()`([документация](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.rand.php)) задаём диапазон значений от `0` до `1` ( 2 переменных ). Функция вернёт вам вам случайный индекс элемента массива. Обращаемся к массиву по индексу и получаем значение.